# NativeBase + Exponent Header

Tags: react-native, native-base, exponentjs

I'm using NativeBase with Exponent. The Header goes beneath the phone's StatusBar. You can see this in the [NativeBase](https://getexponent.com/@community/native-base) demo that Exponent released.

[image]

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: i had the same issue mine mysteriously disappeared after running "yarn install" on the project

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since this issue only comes up in Android, the recommended way to fix this would be to target Android specifically using **Platform** :

```
import {Platform, StatusBar} from 'react-native'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
            flex: 1,
            ...Platform.select({
                android: {
                    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight
                }
            })

        }
})
```

Where container is the main container in the app.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
 // rest of the code here
</View>
```

Comment: By far the best answer I have found so far!

Comment: Please fix `<View style={{styles.container}}>` by removing double brackets. You are assigning an object to style, not declaring one in-place. Edit for peer review must be at least 6 chars long therefore I can't edit it.

Comment: Thanks Varun. Works great fo rme.

Answer (score 6):

I ended up adding a marginTop with the value of the device's StatusBar.

```
import {
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native'
```

In my global stylesheet:

```
header: {
  marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Old post but recently I've faced same issue with Expo. And I overcome this issue by adding this line to app.json file.

> "androidStatusBar": {   "backgroundColor": "#000000" }

app.json file

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "You App Name",    
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    }
  }
}
```

That solved my issue. I think this may help to others.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to handle this using the StyleProvider with my theme, and then into de components folder (native-base-theme/components) found the Header.js file and change the paddintTop value (around 305 line)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for this problem
just import StatusBar component and use this tag:

```
<StatusBar hidden />
```

for example in a page:

```
/*
  Page with no statusbar
*/
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Platform, View, Text, StatusBar} from 'react-native'

export default class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
        <View>
        <StatusBar hidden />
         <Text> Hello World </Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This Component work well with expo and react-native-cli latest virsions.
for more help you can use [ReactNative docs for StatusBar](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html)