# Expo problem Launching app (showing three screen buttons) - React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an expo app that is causing issues on some phones when launching.  Haven't had this issue with the same phone before but haven't opened it on said phone for over a month.

Initially I had 3 test devices and 2 of them were in use everyday, third was only used once to open and test small functionality and then recently (causing this issue).

[After Launching app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7S9f.png)

[How its supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Vjd.png)

Expo SDK: 30

Devices:
iPhone 5c -- Works | 
Samsung S6 -- Works | 
Google Pixel -- Doesn't Work | 
Samsung S7 Edge -- Doesn't Work

Things Tried:

Build and Download APK (unknown sources) -- Same Result | 
Publish to Expo and Open with app (under profile) -- Same Result | 
Connect via CLI (Tunnel & same Network) -- Same Result

** all of these with the exception of APK worked on these devices prior (few weeks)

Comment: This could be a possible solution to your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098186/nativebase-exponent-header

Comment: hey @Andrew thanks but that solution is about clearing the screen from the status bar on android.  My question is about actually launching the app itself.  If you see, the second pic i have the status bar issue solved ;)

Comment: You hadn’t posted the second image when I had responded.

Comment: @Andrew ahh ok no worries!  Yeah I tried to make the title as descriptive as possible knowing the Image may be throwing people off.  That status bar thing is a common issue for sure.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue

Basically, I had a SwitchNavigator and for w.e reason the app was loading that particular page.  For those who have this issue, if you have a device that has this app and you make changes, check the routing to the switch navigator and ensure it doesn't render this first.

For me it was part of the auth flow so it was rendering first but there was some logic that made this particular screen inaccessible for the devices.

Solution 1: make the switch nav a stack or tab
Solution 2: check validation and add logic to pass switch if not needed
Solution 3: remove routing to this page